# Some Transact-SQL queries

Tags: sql

I need help on some SQL select statements.

I have 4 tables:

```
Product(ProductID, Name, DateOfBirth)
Customer(CustomerID, Name)
Comment(CommentID, CustomerID, ProductID, Status)
```

1. Select the products which have not received any comments.
2. Display the customer with the highest number of comments. For example: CusName - Tom, Comment - 3
3. Display all customers with their age, and an additional column which has the value of "Old" for those who are more than 20 years olds, and "Young" for the others.
4. Display the Status column of Comment table as "Enabled" for 1 and "Disabled" for 0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: let's see some attempt. also, whitespace is nice. And your title is poor. And you only have 3 tables not 4!

Comment: Maybe my eyes are playing tricks on me, but I only see three tables.

Comment: You admit to not knowing SQL. But if you don't make an attempt, you won't get any better at it. We are not just going to hand you the answers to your homework.

Comment: You're right that it is just a simple homework, not a real world situation. I am a self-taught SQL learner. That's why I don't have a clue for this. All I know are some basic queries learned from w3schools. If I had a teacher, I would have asked him. I need some examples, so please help.

Comment: If you don't want to do it for me, it would be nice if you give me a clue about what keywords should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part to your question, I would write the SQL this way:

```
SELECT Product.ProductID 
FROM Product
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comment ON Product.ProductID = Comment.ProductID
WHERE Comment.CommentID IS NULL
```

Comment: I managed to do the 2nd query: select top 1 Customers.Name as Customer, count(*) as Comment from Customers inner join Comments on Customers.C_ID=Comments.Cus_ID group by Customers.Name order by Comment desc;

Comment: Managed to do the rest 2 queries using the CASE keyword. Spending an hour searching for it. Before that, I don't even know of that keyword's existence.